# Network goes down intermittently until I unplug the Firewall or Switch cable

Tags: switch, router, firewall, network-access

We have a small office network with 50 workstations/laptops with 10 Mbits/sec Leased line. My Network goes down intermittently until I unplug the Firewall or Switch cable. However I am able to ping the firewall and switch ports from outside. What could be the reason for this?

We have observed a trend. At a particular time(around 9 PM) when a group of 7 to 8 users download movies or stream videos (you tube) concurrently through the wireless router the network goes for a toss and never comes back until we unplug the Firewall or Switch cable. Is this related to data anyway?

Comment: IP conflict on the internal (LAN) side of the firewall?

Comment: looped interface...improper stp config...could be many things...need a config or logging examples.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

50% of network performance drop as i experienced is due to ***LOOP*** , check for a physical loop or if you use Cisco switches check spanning-tree .

Answer (score 1):

Your question is VERY broad, nearly unanswerable. You need to begin by getting some metrics so you can figure out what's going on. Start by buying a solid, commercial grade switch so you can see metrics/usage/errors, etc information. You could have a loop (as suggested in the other answer), a broadcast storm, bad cables, wonky router, nearly anything...

Comment: Thanks @CraigConstantine for your suggestion. We are planning to have a manageable switch and monitor the ports.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a network loop my friend, you must check the logs on the switch, and see was wrong, looking mac address flaping or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience it might be cause by network loop that cause high latency that cause lag on network. Try ping some host and see if there are time out and high latency on it. If so please find the root cause. Also if you you network teaming/bond in windows with broadcom nic please make sure the configuration using anycast not multicast because it can cause multicast storm.